# C++ - Include all sys headers?

Tags: c++, c, system, system-calls

I know you can include a specific header file from `sys`, like `#include <sys/stat.h>`, but can I include *all* of the headers from `sys`?

If this is not possible, could someone point me to where this folder is located?

Comment: No, you can't do this.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i was hoping there was an easier way than including over 300 files... *sigh*

Comment: Do you really need to include all files of sys ? This is a pretty weird idea.

Comment: You really shouldn't need to include all of the files individually... Maybe you should tell us what you're actually trying to do. (See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MichaelWalz I am trying to make a syscall handler for https://github.com/mniip/highlel

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to include all 300 files (at least in a single source file). What you do need is include the files that you actually need to solve your particular problem. They will probably include other sys/*.h. You should never include files that you don't specifically need. Note that sys/ is not just system calls, they are files containing "system specific" (that is, non-standard) functionality.

Comment: You should really post this as a separate question, but consider looking into doing `#include <sys/syscall.h>` (see `man 2 syscall`).

Comment: Remember, each file you include changes the dependency tree for the source file.  So if you include all 300 files, if any one of them changes, especially the ones you don't use, will cause your project to rebuild.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: that's actually not a problem, files in the sys directory dont change, unless you instal la new c programming environnment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include all required headers individually. As workaround you can create header file (e.g. all_sys.h) and put all necessary headers from `sys` into it.

Header files location depends on system/compiler. On my system it's located in `/usr/include/sys`
If you are not sure about location you can look at output of macro-processor. To get it you should use `-E` option (linux/gcc), for instance:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -E | less
```

Notice that if you include redundant headers "just in case" it will increase compilation time unnecessarily